# Advanced Query Counting Dates

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to write a query that will return the number of orders placed during on sales-date vs on non-on sales date for each event in my Event Table.

Orders Table

| OrderID (PK, INT) | OrderDate (DATE) | EventID (INT,FK) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-03-10 | 2 |
| 5 | 2022-03-15 | 2 |

Event Table

| EventID (PK, FK, INT) | NameEvent (VARCHAR) | OnSalesDate (DATE) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | The Rolling Stones | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | The Who Live in Concert | 2022-03-10 |

The Ouput Table should be Something like

| Name_Event | BoughtOnSalesDate | BoughtAfter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The Rolling Stones | 2 | 1 |
| The Who Live in Concert | 1 | 1 |

My current Query that I have so far is:

```
SELECT OrderDate , EventName

FROM Orders

Left JOIN Event on Orders.EventID = Event.EventID

WHERE Orders.OrderDate = Event.OnSaleDate

ORDER BY OrderDate;
```

Which Outputs:

| OrderDate | EventName |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | The Rolling Stones |
| 2022-01-01 | The Rolling Stones |
| 2022-03-10 | The Who Live in Concert |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Group BY the data of event to get your wanted result

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Orders  (
>   `OrderID` INTEGER,
>   `OrderDate` VARCHAR(10),
>   `EventID` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Orders 
>   (`OrderID`, `OrderDate`, `EventID`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2022-01-01', '1'),
>   ('2', '2022-01-12', '1'),
>   ('3', '2022-01-01', '1'),
>   ('4', '2022-03-10', '2'),
>   ('5', '2022-03-15', '2');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Event  (
>   `EventID` INTEGER,
>   `NameEvent` VARCHAR(23),
>   `OnSalesDate` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Event 
>   (`EventID`, `NameEvent`, `OnSalesDate`) 
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'The Rolling Stones', '2022-01-01'),
>   ('2', 'The Who Live in Concert', '2022-03-10');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `NameEvent`,`OnSalesDate`
> , SUM(`OnSalesDate` = `OrderDate`) BoughtOnSalesDate
> , SUM(`OnSalesDate` < `OrderDate`)  BoughtAfter
> FROM Orders
> Left JOIN Event on Orders.EventID = Event.EventID
> GROUP  BY Orders.`EventID`, `NameEvent`,`OnSalesDate`
> ORDER BY `OnSalesDate`;
> ```
>
> ```
> NameEvent               | OnSalesDate | BoughtOnSalesDate | BoughtAfter
> :---------------------- | :---------- | ----------------: | ----------:
> The Rolling Stones      | 2022-01-01  |                 2 |           1
> The Who Live in Concert | 2022-03-10  |                 1 |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37f726c79cb2c2fcb1664d6dede0e8cd)*

Comment: no problem the `OnSalesDate` = `OrderDate` returns 1 if the dates are equal and 0 if not the sqme goes for the  <